# Conditional grouping in a pivoty query mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

My schema looks like,

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CategoryName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


INSERT INTO `test`
(`Id`,
`CategoryName`,
`type`,
`value`)
VALUES
(1 ,'Allowance' ,'ADDITION',4000),
(1,'Salary' ,'ADDITION',1500),
(1,'Telephone' ,'ADDITION',200),
(1,'Other' ,'ADDITION',500),
(1,'Fine' ,'DEDUCTION',500),
(1,'Other Deduction' ,'DEDUCTION',500),
(1,'Salary Deduction' ,'DEDUCTION',100),
(2,'Salary' ,'ADDITION',300),
(2,'Other' ,'ADDITION',1300)
;
```

The requirement is to show certain categories summed up and others as is. In this case Salary & Allowance to be shown on their own columns, while any other addition type to be summed up. Same applies to the deduction type.

```
select Id,MAX(CASE
        WHEN CategoryName = 'Salary' THEN pi.value
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'Salary',  
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN CategoryName = 'Allowance' THEN pi.value
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'Allowance',  
    MAX(CASE when pi.type = 'ADDITION' THEN
    CASE
        WHEN CategoryName not in ('Salary','Allowance') THEN pi.value -- sum(pi.value)
        ELSE 0
        END
    END) AS 'Other Allowances',
    MAX(case WHEN CategoryName = 'Fine' THEN pi.value -- sum(pi.value)
        ELSE 0            
    END) AS 'Fine' ,        
     MAX(CASE when pi.type = 'DEDUCTION' THEN
    CASE
        WHEN CategoryName not in ( 'Fine') THEN pi.value -- sum(pi.value)
        ELSE 0
        END
    END) AS 'Other Deductions' 
     from  test pi group by Id;
```

Now when i put `sum(pi.value)` I get error *Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function*. Without the sum function the max is returning the max value only and ignoring the rest, like the Telephone addition, which is as expected.

```
Id  Salary      Allowance   Other Allowances    Fine     Other Deductions
1   1500.0000   4000.0000    500.0000          500.0000    500.0000
2   300.0000    0.0000       1300.0000          0.0000      *null*
```

So the *Other Allowance* column for id 1 should show *700 i.e. 500 (Other) + 200 (Telephone)*

What would be the right way to get the sum in this case while using the pivot query ?

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ed955a777e6cf8632a71f07358c1607)

Comment: Note that, by convention, columns called 'id' are usually the (surrogate) primary key of a given table. That aside, consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: It worked, when I use `SUM` for condition https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92d917a2cf660c21dce3bd56fc6f0cb6

Comment: @D-Shih Nice one

Comment: And remember, if sticking with your approach, you're not obliged to use MAX. Other aggregate functions are available.